# Where should I take visa photo for Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, italy, washington-dc

I am applying for Italy short stay visa at Washington DC. In the appointment confirmation email, it is stated for photo requirement as

```
Recent passport-size photo (1.2”x1.5” or 4x4 cm) on white background (NOTE: scanned or photocopied photos will NOT be accepted).
```

I emailed visti.washington@esteri.it and they confirmed with this response,

```
4x4cm (white background!).
```

In US, stores like walgreens and CVS provide default Schengen visa size like 35mm x 45 mm. Where can we get the photo with this special dimension?

Comment: The dimensions are probably not all that important since `1.2"×1.4"` corresponds to 31mm × 38 mm ...

Comment: That is a strange thing for the embassy to say. The Schengen visa dimensions should be fine, since they are issuing Schengen visas!

Comment: Luckily we found a photo studio in a shopping mall where they could take a 4 cm x 4 cm photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a photo studio in a shopping mall where they could take a 4 cm x 4 cm photo. So its better to check with a studio if they can make 4 cm x 4 cm.